# How do I easily convert a streaming array to variables?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pyaudio

I tried to find this answer, and after several hours, still no results. I want to do something very easy, this doesn't have to be this complicated...

So, we have a pyaudio buffer that pulls a chunk of 4095 variables like this:

```
class audio_stream(Process):
    CHUNK = 4095  # number of data points to read at a time
    RATE = 48000  # time resolution of the recording device (Hz)
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # start the PyAudio class
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, input_device_index=1, channels=8, rate=RATE, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)  # uses default input device
    # create a numpy array holding a single read of audio data
```

and something to convert this stream to a usable numpy array with this:

```
        data = numpy.frombuffer(audio_stream.stream.read(audio_stream.CHUNK), dtype=numpy.float32)
```

For a result that looks like this:

```
[ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00 -3.0517578e-05 ...  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
```

If I convert this to a DataFrame, it resolves like this:

```
0      0.000000
1      0.000000
2     -0.000031
3      0.000000
4      0.000000
...         ...
32755  0.000000
32756 -0.000031
32757  0.000000
32758  0.000000
32759  0.000000

[32760 rows x 1 columns]
```

It clearly lists an index # (that goes from, I guess, 0 to 32760) and then the floating point values.

I'm trying to simply assign the index value (0-32760) to a variable like x,
and assign the floating values to a variable like y.

I've tried this:

```
for index, value in zip(range(len(data)), data):
```

with no success, it just throws an error or fails completely.

Trying to send this to river which expects csv format as well.

This array information is streaming information, it pulls 4095 unique values everytime it loops.

Any easy suggestions? I feel this could be easily accomplished with some module.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little bit confused.  You seem to have an array `data`.  What is it you're trying to generate?    And by the way, your complicated `zip` statement appears to just be `enumerate(data)`.

Comment: Hey Frank, to clarify i'm trying to get a streaming pyAudio array to work with scikit-multiflow. Their DataStream function says it accepts numpy arrays or dataframes, yet converting this to that format causes me more errors than I can count. Does that help at all? Any suggestions?

Comment: what are the variables you try to get? `data` is already numpy array. `index` is just `np,arange(len(data))`